# no such table: accounts_demandplan

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Django project, '**MyAPP**' I had a model as ***accounts_demandplan*** which I have unfortunately deleted from my Jupyter notebook by connecting to my sqlite3.db. Following is the SQL code I executed.

```
import sqlite3 
import pandas as pd 
conn = sqlite3.connect("C:/Users\Parijat\Desktop\Theis project\CRM\db.sqlite3") 
cur = conn.cursor() 
cur.execute(" DROP TABLE accounts_demandplan")
```

I know that I did not do the migrations properly and it is now showing the following error

```
OperationalError: no such table: accounts_demandplan
```

Can anyone help how can I resolve the problem so that the deleted model "account_demandplan"
can be reflected in my migrations file?

Comment: delete all the files in all migration folders in all apps except __init.py__ files. And also delete db.sqlite3 file.run python manage.py migrate > python manage.py makemigrations. Note that you would loose all the previous data in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the migrations folder in the app you are working in.

Generally if you need to make changes to a database in django you should strictly do it via models and migrations.

However before deleting make a copy of your database for good measure. You don't want to lose all your data.